# Get all values via AJAX and display in div (ASP.NET)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have table with records

I need to display all records in div by button

I have this AJAX call like this

```
<script>
     $('#save_quest').click(function() {
    email_update();
});

function email_update() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("EmailsList", "Questions")',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        //data: JSON.stringify(model),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            var question1 = data[0];

            $(".email_list")
                .append(
                    '<div class="testing666" style="width:80%;font-size:20px;margin-top:15px;border-style: solid;border-color:#ffcf00;border-radius: 5px;margin: 10px auto 0;;">' +
                    question1 +
                    '</div>');
            var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

            for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
                if (divs[i].innerHTML == "") {
                    divs[i].style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Here is controller (updated)

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EmailsList()
    {
        var items_email = db.InvitationMails
            .Select(x=> new
            {
                Email = x.To.ToString(),
                Name = x.Name.ToString(),
            })
            .ToList();
        return Json(items_email, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

What I need to write here , to display all data according to controller select

```
//data: JSON.stringify(model)
```

Comment: So, what is the problem here? Are you getting data back from the controller at all or you aren't getting any data from the controller?

Comment: I updated my post@ProgrammerV5

Comment: Still, you've updated the controller code. Is the controller being hit (I mean, do you know if the controller is being hit? Did you put a line of code at the beginning of the controller and checked that the AJAX call is being ran and hitting the controller correctly? There are several things that can go wrong, the AJAX call can be set up incorrectly, the controller might not be called in the way it should, the controller might not be returning the correct data, the AJAX call might not be interpreting the data returned by the controller.

Comment: If your controller doesn't get any parameter. You can't use "data: JSON.stringify(model)". When your type is post

Answer (score 0):

In controller you have no parameters. So you don't need to pass anything in data of ajax.

Answer (score 0):

We need a lot more information. Open up the browser tools and test the request. What do you see? What is the response? Is your request being routed to the right controller? Is the controller not responding? What is going on? Your request for help is far too vague to actually be helped.

Why are you using `POST` if you're not sending any data? If you don't intend to send any data and just want to get the `EmailsList` then use a `GET`, and change the `[HttpPost]` attribute to `[HttpGet]`. If you want to use a `POST` then remove `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`. There isn't any use for exposing a `GET` if you don't actually need to expose it. Your controller method doesn't require any parameters so a simple get will do.